# A result used in the proof of Bezout's theorem.

Tags: algebraic-curves, projective-space, plane-curves

I am reading Fulton's book and I have reached the proof of Bezout's theorem which states that:

> *Theorem:* If $F$ and $G$ are two projective plane curves of degrees $m$ and $n$ respectively and they have no common factor,then $\sum\limits_{p} I(p,F\cap G)=mn$.

The proof uses the following result:

> *Lemma:* If $F$ and $G$ are two projective plane curves and they have no common factor,then they intersect at finitely many points only.

But although I have understood the proof of Bezout's theorem,the only problem is that I have assumed this lemma(as I could not give a proof).Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you can show this result for affine curves, here is a big hint: choose a line $\ell$ such that $F\cap\ell$ and $G\cap\ell$ are finite. Then choose coordinates so that $\ell$ is the zero set of one of your projective coordinates. Verify the complement of $\ell$ is affine. Then show that $F\cap\ell^c$ and $G\cap\ell^c$ are finite.